# AS3 NetStatusEvent events not triggered

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, video-streaming

`NetStatusEvent` has only one type of event: `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS`; but it comes with many codes for various cases.

[Here they are, listed.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#info)

However, a lot of them are not triggered for me. I know some are FMS specific but I'm talking about "`NetStream.Play.Stop`", "`NetStream.Pause.Notify`" or "`NetStream.Unpause.Notify`".

Is there a case when they shouldn't be triggered, even though I'm calling NetStream's control functions (which take effect), or a known issue around this matter?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using?  I'm running into the same issue, but only on Mac OS X.  The NetStatusEvents are being fired on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to guess.

Maybe check the obvious first: are you sure you added a listener to the NetStream instance?
Since both NetConnection and NetStream dispatch NetStatusEvent you may have only added the listener to your NetConnection instance.